# Will airport terminal Baggage Wrap companies accept bicycles?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, bicycles

Comments on question and answers to [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/98190/2509) contains some discussion about whether to send a bicycle in a box or loose, if the airline will accept it.  For protection, can I expect baggage wrap companies (like [this one](https://www.bagwrap.com/)) to accept a bicycle (pre-processed such as pedals taken off and handlebar turned)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many baggage wrap machines can not handle something the size of a bicycle.  They maybe able to hand wrap it, but once you do the advantage of being able to easily handle it goes away because of the tight film.  Also the wheels will not roll, relegating it to the same mishandling as a big box.

Comment: When I wrapped my backpack, they cut a hole at the end for easier handling.  They could easily do the same for bicycle wheels.

Comment: If you cut the plastic away to let the wheels roll, there wouldn't much wrapped.

Comment: Frame, seat, handlebar, hub generator, lights, brakes, hub gear, frame lock, luggage rack, …

Comment: @gerrit - To wrap the bike AND leave the wheels free to roll, would require removing the wheels, hand wrapping each of the three frame triangles, forks, seat and handlebars, then replacing the wheels without tearing the wrap on the rear triangles.  If you have disc brakes you would have to uncover the brake wraps to allow the discs to slide in.  Bottom line, it is not very effective as a whole.  But as a courtesy to your fellow travelers, you might want to wrap some plastic around your chain, unless you are meticulous about chain cleaning.